# ldapsearch - truncating the result

Tags: ldap, opendj

I am using `ldapsearch` for getting radius secret, but it is giving truncated result

Command I am using is :

```
./ldapsearch -p 1545 -Z -X -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w passwd -b "o=platform" "(objectClass=*)" | grep -i secret
```

result produced is :

> > ss-secret=ahksdf6fakh7fajkfhaffjkfjfhafajkfh234578fajf171jkh25/525jhsfasjh8jjk7

where as actual value in LDAP is

> > ss-secret=ahksdf6fakh7fajkfhaffjkfjfhafajkfh234578fajf171jkh25/525jhsfasjh8jjk7afjfh8/gSqtulkjfa8lfjakl3

I am using OpenDJ LDAP.

Comment: `ldapsearch` is wrapping by default. Your grep is only getting the matching line and not the subsequently line(s) that are part of it. As @curtis-yallop noted below, `ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no ...` with your grep should solve this problem. Pls give him cred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -T argument like

```
./ldapsearch -p 1545 -T -Z -X -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w passwd -b "o=platform" "(objectClass=*)" | grep -i secret
```

This will give you complete output.

Answer (score 15):

Try "ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no ...".

Search the man page for "wrap".

I am using OpenLDAP in the ldap-utils package on debian.

Answer (score 2):

for Debian based system you have to add "-o ldif-wrap=no "
example: `ldapsearch -xLLL -o ldif-wrap=no -H ldap://hostname:port/`
 from the man page of ldapsearch ubuntu 16.04:

> -T path
>     Write temporary files to directory specified by path (default: /var/tmp/)

so it has no relation with formatting the output

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of those options worked for me. I went to trusty sed and awk and solved the problem.

```sh
ldapsearch options > outfile
## sed to remove the space at the beginning of wrapped lines.
sed -i 's/^ //g' outfile
## Awk to join the lines if 78
awk '{if(length($0) == 78) {printf $0} else {print $0} }' outfile > outfile.nowrap
```

Answer (score -1):

Going to try the wrap thing but this has been my go-to for years:

```
ldapsearch -xLLL cn=WHATEVER | perl -p00e 's/\n /g'
```

It’s ugly, which is why I landed here looking for a better way, but it works without fail.